# How, and what to expect when switching fields (from bachelors to masters)?

Tags: masters, bachelor

**Just context, you can skip directly to the question at the bottom should you wish to.**

I'm currently on my 4th out of a 6 semester pure mathematics Bachelors. My grades are 4.0x-ish out of 5, which is good for the 2nd highest for my batch (but I'm guessing for most Mathematicians, and even for myself, it's either A's or you don't understand). I had passion doing mathematics at school (several medals in international math Olympiads), and still get that glee when learning the material given to me.

The issue is I've been noticing several red flags (for the first time I was in a real danger to fail a course, though in the end I still got a B), and starting to find out the limit of my capabilities (I can understand the material just fine, during the semester. Can't recall anything afterwards).

Another issue is I have no love for the academic world (sorry!), and would prefer a professional career instead. Thus, I want to switch from a 'pure' field to a more 'applied' one.

**Question:** What to expect when switching my field of studies? How should I prepare for it? I'm open to reading/learning the basics by myself so as to be a little more prepared. Are there things that I should be aware of?

Comment: If your inclination in not toward a career in academia, get involved with internships with small, large, new, old organizations offering them. It’ll be a solid complement to your classroom education.

Comment: An unfortunate consequence of the pandemic is that a lot of companies are withdrawing their internship programs, and the ones that retain them keep it for locals (I'm studying outside of my country).